# how to contentResovlver within a Fragment?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

contentResolver is Unresolved reference: contentResolver how do I rectify this?

```
class fragment_edcards_media_animimage : Fragment() {
// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private var param1: String? = null
private var param2: String? = null
lateinit var u : FragmentEdcardsMediaAnimimageBinding

// Animated Image
private val getContentCardAnimImage = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent())  { uri: Uri ->

    val contentResolver = contentResolver
    val source = ImageDecoder.createSource( contentResolver, uri )
    val drawable = ImageDecoder.decodeDrawable(source)

    Log.d("EditCards",uri.toString())

    //u.iViewAnimImage.setImageDrawable(drawable)
    if (drawable is AnimatedImageDrawable){
        drawable.start()
        //drawable.repeatCount = 2
    }

    val file = File( uri?.path )
    mydecklist[cCardPosition].c_animimageuri = mytools.getImageFromMediaStore(u.iViewAnimImage.context,file.name)
}
```

Attempt #1
activity.contentResovlver results in;
Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type FragmentActivity?

Attempt #2
val contentResolver = activity?.contentResolver

val source = ImageDecoder.createSource( **contentResolver**, uri )
Type mismatch: inferred type is ContentResolver? but ContentResolver was expected

I've bolded where it thinks the error is in the line ImageDecoder.

Attempt #3
val contentResolver = getActivity().contentResolver()
Expression 'contentResolver' of type 'ContentResolver!' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found

And

Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type FragmentActivity?

Comment: try using `!!`  where not null are needed

Comment: `val contentResolver = requireActivity().contentResolver`

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the answer; val contentResolver = requireActivity().contentResolver

thanks CommonsWave